# efficient way to find the max displacement between a repeating integer in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the max difference between two sequential occurrence of the same integer in an efficient way. I can try a loop but my dataset is >100,000 rows which is incredibly cumbersome. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
data = np.random.randint(5,30,size=100000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['random_numbers'])
```

Example:
In my sample, the max difference between this sequential occurrence of `5` is `29 - 5 = 24`.

```
df.loc[79:93].values
array([[ 5],
       [17],
       [ 7],
       [15],
       [25],
       [23],
       [24],
       [22],
       [21],
       [29],
       [25],
       [28],
       [13],
       [19],
       [ 5]])
```

Comment: Why is `29`? Because is the maximum between the two 5?

Comment: yes, 29 is the max value between the 2 occurrences of 5

Comment: so you will provide an integer and the code should give you the max-min of the numbers between that integer and the next time is shows up, right?

Comment: close, not the max min, but the max difference (so technically absolute value) between the provided integer and the max or the min value between that integer and the next time it shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
g = df['random_numbers'].eq(5).cumsum()
df.groupby(g).max() - 5
```

Output with smaller data:

```
data = np.random.randint(5,30,size=30)
# array([28, 19, 29, 22, 10, 18, 13, 14, 25, 24, 21, 24, 10, 20, 20,  5, 23,
#         8, 29, 22, 24, 24, 24, 19, 12,  5,  6, 14,  5, 15])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['rand_nums'])
g = df['rand_nums'].eq(5).cumsum()

# Look at both df and g
# print(pd.concat([df, g], axis=1) # just for explanation.

    rand_nums  rand_nums
0          28          0  ⟶ group 1 starts here
1          19          0
2          29          0
3          22          0
4          10          0
5          18          0
6          13          0
7          14          0  # we take max from here i.e. 29.
8          25          0
9          24          0
10         21          0
11         24          0
12         10          0
13         20          0
14         20          0 ⟶ group1 ends here
15          5          1 ⟶ group2 starts here
16         23          1
17          8          1
18         29          1
19         22          1
20         24          1 # take max from here i.e 29
21         24          1
22         24          1
23         19          1
24         12          1 ⟶ group2 ends here.
25          5          2 ⟶ grp 3 starts here.
26          6          2 # take max from here i.e. 14
27         14          2 ⟶ grp 3 ends here.
28          5          3 ⟶ grp4 starts here. # take max from here i.e. 15
29         15          3 ⟶ grp4 ends here.
```

That gives us:

```
df.groupby(g).max() - 5

           rand_nums
rand_nums           
0                 24
1                 24
2                  9
3                 10
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    df.loc[79:93].max() - df.loc[79:93].min()
```

EDIT:

```
index_integer = df.index[df['random_numbers'] == 5] # change 5 for your 
max_disp = []
for i in index[:-1]:
    max_displ.append(df[index[i]:index[i+1].max() - df[index[i]:index[i+1].mmin())
```

using comprehension list:

```
index_integer = df.index[df['random_numbers'] == 5] # change 5 for your number
max_displ = [df[l[i]:l[i+1]].max() - df[l[i]:l[i+1]].min() for i in range(0,len(l[:-1]))]
```

Comment: you didn't understand my question, this is an example to help you understand what I'm looking for, not literally find the max difference for this instance.

Comment: Then explain better.....The code provides the same result as you stated on the example....